# What is the use case for multi-type-parameter generics?

Tags: type-theory, abstract-data-types

In C#, one can define a class/method/function with multiple type parameters. For example,

```
// function
void foo<T1, T2>(T1 x, T2 y) { /*body*/}

// class
class Bar<T1, T2> { /*body*/ }
```

I understand **how** to use it, but I don't understand **why** I need it. So I'm hoping someone can answer the following questions:

1) What is the use case for multiple type parameters?

2) Based on the use case given in Question 1, what are the alternative solutions for that use case if multiple type parameters is not a feature of the language in use?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/95280/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51348045/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: "but I don't understand why I need it." You don't need high-level programming language at all, you can do anything on asm. But somewhy you prefer not to program on asm when you can do it on C#.

Comment: @D.W. It depends on the context of the case. If the same question could and should be answered from different perspectives on different sites, it's nothing wrong to post it on both. Another question is whether it should be answered from different perspectives. Computer scientist vs. programmer.

Comment: @rus9384, I appreciate your reasoning, but that's [not what our community policy says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/160917).

Comment: @D.W. I believe the example was pretty bad. More robust one would be to ask the same question on philosophy and buddhism.

Comment: @D.W. I also seriously thinks that it is not reasonable, because I wanted to get different answers from different point of views.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some use cases for multiple type arguments include

- maps/dictionaries `Map<K,V>`, where you have one key parameter and one value parameter
- product types `Pair<A,B>`
- sum types, AKA variants `Variant<A,B>`, which represent a value which might be either of type `A` or of type `B`
- Function-like types `Func<A,B>` representing a function from `A` to `B`
- "Visitor" objects for parametric types. I.e. a visitor for `List<A>` is `ListVisitor<A,R>` where `R` is the return type of the visitor.

If we did not have multiple type arguments, or any other way to emulate multiple argument types (e.g. nested parametric classes `class T<A> { class U<B> { ...` which are a sort-of curried version of the two-arguments class), we could not express the examples above in a generic way.

Of course, a programming language could disallow generic classes and still have a specific primitive type for some of the examples above. For instance, `Func<A,B>` could be a primitive type, instead of a user/library-defined class type.

Comment: Multiple types are also redundant if product types are primitive types (e.g. `(Int, String)`) and the language offers projection operators on these pairs: `class Map<T> { /* use first(T) and second(T) as types here */ }`. Then one only needs to write `Map<(Int, String)>`.

Comment: @ComFreek You can't define `Map` that way. `Map` is a constructor of kind `* -> * -> *`. You're approach would make it `* -> *`, which couldn't enforce the type parameter to be a pair. That's exactly why we have kinds.

Comment: @gardenhead Just create a compiler error when `T` is not a pair... (at least C++ allows that)

Comment: @gardenhead: I think you're assuming too much about other properties of the language. There's no reason that the language couldn't let `Map` impose constraints on its type parameter, analogous to Haskell typeclasses, C# `where` constraints, Java `extends` bounds, etc.

Comment: @ruakh That's precisely what kinds are for... imposing constraints on a type constructor.

Comment: @gardenhead: Well, so what? No one here is claiming that you *can't* implement `Map` as `* -> * -> *`; but in C# it's `(*, *) -> *` (which is what the question is about), and ComFreek is pointing out that it can also be implemented as something like `(Pair :: *) -> *`. If it bothers you that different languages can accomplish the same thing in different ways, then this may not be the site for you. :-/

Comment: @ruakh This is *computer science* stack exchange, not C# stack exchange. This may not be the site for you

Comment: @chi Just want to inform you why I haven't accept your answer, because most of your points stated can be described using a functional syntax :  
- sum types? `type Animal = Dog | Cat | Lion`  
- product types? `type Pair = Int * Int`   
- Function types? `sum :: Int a => [a] -> a` etc. actually  I'm looking for something that could not be described by functional syntax, something more complex or sophisticated. Anyway your answer did provide my with some insights though, so thank you :)  P/S: I did upvoted your answer.

Comment: @WongJiaHau Note that a parametric product `type Pair a b = a * b` still requires two type parameters. Or `type Cont r a = (a -> r) -> r` for continuations. Or the state monad. Or many monad transformers. If you want to see complex examples, and are willing to add more features to the language, I think that GADTs provide plenty of examples for non trivial uses of multiple type parameters. E.g. https://gist.github.com/rampion/2659812

Comment: @chi Thanks, would you like to summarize the non-trivial uses in your answer so that I can understand it better? Because I don't really understand the Haskell code you gave me . . .